# How to change default error page(status 404 - not found) in GlassFish 3.0.1 Community Edition?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

How to change default error page(status 404 - not found) in GlassFish 3.0.1 Community Edition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using the glassfish console and add a property here:

*Configuration|Virtual Server|server*

name: **send-error_1**

value: **code=404 path=/tmp/404.html reason=Resource_not_found**

Increase the number for several errors, eg. send_error_2,3,4...

Paths are either absolute or relative to your domain folder.

Have a look at http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/customized-error-pages-for-glassfish-v3/

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this, using the excellent link above. However, the HTML error page we set with path= comes back in the browser as plain text with all HTML tags visible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Create a page 404.htm

Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>404 - Page not found.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family:tahoma;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="firstWarning">Page not found.</div>
    <img src="css/images/404.jpg" class="imgWarning" />
</body>
</html>
```

and save it as 404.htm and put it to your

```
${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/docroot/
```

Ex:

```
/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/
```

Enter:

```
https://ip_address:4848/web/configuration/virtualServerEdit.jsf?name=server&configName=server-config
```

Add new property to server

```
Name:send-error_1
Value:code=404 path=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/docroot/404.htm reason=Resource_not_found
Description: 404 Error Page
```

[image]
[image]
[image]